# nodejs memory leak error

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks

I am new to nodejs. Recently my application stopped with this error. I was unable to understand what the problem is and please provide me some clarity about this, whether it is memory leak or any thing else.

Here is the error:

<--- Last few GCs --->

```
73692790 ms: Mark-sweep 1391.7 (1457.7) -> 1390.4 (1457.7) MB, 1069.2 / 0 ms (+ 4095.2 ms in 21 steps since start of marking, biggest step 3236.5 ms) [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
73697149 ms: Mark-sweep 1390.4 (1457.7) -> 1390.2 (1457.7) MB, 4358.3 / 0 ms [last resort gc].
73701508 ms: Mark-sweep 1390.2 (1457.7) -> 1390.2 (1457.7) MB, 4359.2 / 0 ms [last resort gc].
```

<--- JS stacktrace --->

```
==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x2631dd5e3ac1 <JS Object>
    1: write [buffer.js:~539] [pc=0x3a11fc6eddca] (this=0x39392beb1331 <an Uint8Array with map 0x2ef559505289>,string=0x34057c5f7b09 <Very long string[2737]>,offset=0,length=0x2631dd5ed8d9 <String[4]: utf8>,encoding=0x2631dd504189 <undefined>)
    2: arguments adaptor frame: 3->4
    3: new constructor(aka Buffer) [buffer.js:~44] [pc=0x3a11fc652b38] (this=0x39392beb1381 <a Buffer with map 0x2ef...
```

Comment: I'm not positive, but it looks like you attempted to do something with a 4 terabyte string. Are you trying to read a massive file or something?

Comment: Either 

* You'r working on a large dataset that take all your max-old-space (1.4Gb by default), best way is to try to make your code iterate on smaller chunk of data.

* You've got yourself a leak.

We need more info like code and what you'r trying to do with node.
Also, in case of a leak you would generally see an incremental increase of memory taken after each GC, so the general trend of the memory during X hours would be great (a graph could be kind of hard to get, so just you'r appreciation of the evolution could do).